# C Command-line interface - History function like in BASH

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, command-line

Good day,

I am writing a simple CLI (command-line interface) application that provides a simple prompt that can accept strings from the user, validates them, and performs certain actions based on input. Fairly straightforward.

I am looking for a platform independent, NON-GPL/LGPL means (or, at least something that works for POSIX compliant OS's, like Linux, BSD, etc), so I can use the up/down arrows keys to scroll back and forth throughout the history of previously typed commands in my CLI application, and have them appear in the input line.

The goal is to effectively mimic the history feature found in BASH and most other shells. I would like to just use the up/down keys and have them detected. I'm assuming I would need to use interrupts or some specialized library for this; I would really like to just do this with standard ANSI C though, and must avoid any third party libraries entirely.

Comment: Probably ncurses will do most of the work for you, in a platform-independent way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you insist on doing it yourself, then there's not much we can say other than "do it yourself;" it's not horribly complex but it's not a morning's work, either.

You should very seriously consider using [GNU `readline`](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline/), which is what everybody else (including `bash`) uses. It does all this and more and does it well.

Answer (score 5):

You can use readline, or you can take the easy route and do absolutely nothing.  When you run your program, invoke it via rlwrap and you get history editing for free.  In other words, instead of:

```
$ mytool
```

you just run

```
$ rlwrap mytool
```

rlwrap is a wrapper around readline which allows you to get the benefits of readline without doing any work.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about `rlwrap`. I've used Java versions of the same idea. Note that on Windows, console programs get readline-like behavior by default!

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library which is what bash uses. Note that this is GPL so your code would have to be internal or GPL. There is libedit which is BSD licensed that has less functionality

Answer (score 1):

As the stated on the other answers, you really should use readline. Otherwise you're going to have to use a buffer, and use the stdin file descriptor with `read()`. You're going to need to setup a data structure and/or file that contains your history. Also, you can use `execvp()` and/or `system()` to dispatch commands.